# More efficient way to remove items from large data sets

Tags: python

I have two large lists:

```
a = [['abcdefghijklmno', 'foo', 'bar'], … ]
b = [['abcdefghij12345', 'foo', 'bar'], … ]
```

I'm interested in all members of `a` which don't have a corresponding entry in `b`, and vice versa, based on comparing `a[n][0]` and `b[n][0]` for all *n* in `a` and `b`. I create two sets of these sublist items, which allows me to do `set_a.difference(set_b)`, and vice versa, which is very fast. But creating two lists based on the remaining items in `a` and `b` is (perhaps obviously) slower:

```
def remaining(ls ,y, z):
    return [i for i in ls if i[0] in y.difference(z)]
```

where `ls` is either `a` or `b`, and `y` and `z` are the two sets detailed above. Is there any point in rethinking the structure of `a` and `b` to speed this up (e.g. using dicts with `a[0]` and `b[0]` values as the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your test in the list comprehension is calling y.difference for each element.  Try this:

```
def remaining(ls, y, z):
    diff = y.difference(z)
    return filter(lambda i: i[0] in diff, ls)
```

Comment: Testing against 10k-item lists, it's now almost instant. I should probably test more thoroughly, but your suspicion would appear to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

At least `def remaining(ls ,y, z):` should be rewritten in `def remaining(ls, common_set):`.

Consider the next idea: wrap `['abcdefghijklmno', 'foo', 'bar']` in an object (probably with `__slots__`) and define its `__hash__` using only `'abcdefghijklmno'` value. After that you will be able to do `set(a) - set(b)` and get you task solved.

Comment: Don't you just want the intersection?

Comment: @urschrei it is still just an idea.  i will be glad to hear about your result with it.

Comment: @Roman Bodnarchuk Certainly sounds promising. I'll try it out.